# Android SQLite equals query

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

Okay I am attempting to work with a ListView and SQLite database, Basically I have a table that consist of

Title | Day | Description

Buy Milk | Tuesday | Buy milk at store

Above shows what the table will hold. So I want to query this data where it will only retrieve ALL tuesday reminders and display it on the ListView this will also be the same for the rest of the days. Is this possible? If so how can I approach this?

I have already created the Table but dont know how to query this properly where if real time date equals Tuesday get all Tuesday data from SQLite database, What do I pass into my DBHelper which handles all db queries

```
    public void getTodayData()
    {
          String days[]={"Sunday","Monday"....}; write all 7 days
          String day=days[(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))-1];

Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DBHelper.Title_NAME, DBHelper.Description}, new String[]{ "Day" }, new String[]{ getDay(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) }, null, null, null);

return c;
    }
```

The above code is me trying to attemp this query, do i need to call on Calendar object or something to get the day?. **The overall question is how to query a data where if REAL TIME DAY is equals to savedData Day then retrieve all data that equals to REAL TIME DAY**

Comment: Create a function which calls something like this "select * from TABLE were Day = "Tuesday""

Comment: @apmartin1991 I understand I can easily make a query to bring data that holds Tuesday in their row but I want it so it does it for all days, so it compares real time day to saved day in SQL

Answer (score 0):

First, add a method in your class (it can be in your DBHelper) to get the name of the current day when you pass this number as parameter:

```
public String getDay(int day)
{
    if(day==1) return "Sunday";
    else if(day==2) return "Monday";
    ...
}
```

And then, you should do the query as follows:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DBHelper.Title_NAME, DBHelper.Description}, new String[]{ "Day" }, new String[]{ getDay(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Yes but I want to retrieve data which corresponds to the real time day so I dont need to manually query each day? What would I need to return and what would by method need as an input? I dont want to query just tuesday I want it to it query the data depending on the real time day. So for example. Today is Friday, then the query should obtain all friday data when the user wants to view today's reminders

Comment: Okay I see now, so the Calendar method should I implement that in the DBHelper? and how can I pass the getDay string to the query?

Comment: I have edited my question. Calendar is a Singleton, so you don't need to instantiate it to get the current day.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a String array as follows

```
String days[]={"Sunday","Monday"....}; write all 7 days

String day=days[(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))-1];
```

and in query

```
 Cursor c = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DBHelper.Title_NAME, DBHelper.Description}, new String[]{ "Day" }, new String[]{day}, null, null, null);
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Will this mean that I dont need to create a Calendar object instance but just implement the string into getTodayData() ? What will i need to return? Can you write out in my getTodayData method

Comment: If you want data of current day return cursor it will contain data of current day.

Comment: Thank you i will attempt this, so will I declare String days and day in the same method as getTodayData? I have updated the code does that seem right